# Phoenix queryserver 413 HTTP Error

Tags: http, apache-phoenix

When I send a large query to phoenix queryserver I get the error 413.

Is there a way to increase the request size in queryserver to handle my request correctly?

Comment: Phoenix uses Jetty server

Comment: I could not solve the problem just used Phoenix 4.7 and Phoenixdb v1.6 which will send the query in the body instead of the header